# Fill remaining parent height in ChakraUI

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, chakra-ui

[image]

I'm using ChakraUI for the Card, Button and Select, and Chartjs for the Linegraph, the problem I'm having is that the Chart is not fitting the card properly as you can see in the image, probably due to the fact that the Box being returned in the component has a Flex with the button and select in addition to the chart itself, because of that the chart fills the Box while ignoring the Flex, going out of bounds, but I can't find a solution, what I want is to have the chart fill the remaining height of the card, the card is in the parent component not in this child component, since the card component is resizable setting a fixed height will be a problem.

WeeklyScoreGraph.js

```
const options = {
maintainAspectRatio: false,
responsive: true,
scales: {
  y: {
    max:
      Math.max(...score_logs.map((score_log) => score_log.new_score)) + 5,
    grid: {
      display: false,
    },
  },
  x: {
    grid: {
      display: false,
    },
  },
},
plugins: {
  zoom: {
    pan: {
      enabled: true,
      mode: "x",
      modifierKey: "ctrl",
    },
    zoom: {
      drag: {
        enabled: true,
      },
      mode: "x",
    },
  },
  legend: {
    display: false,
  },
  title: {
    display: true,
    text: "Histórico do Score",
  },
  datalabels: {
    anchor: "end",
    align: "end",
  },
},
segment: {
  borderColor: function (context) {
    const chart = context.chart;
    const { ctx, chartArea } = chart;

    if (!chartArea) {
      // This case happens on initial chart load
      return;
    }
    return getGradient(ctx, chartArea);
  },

  //ctx.chart.data.datasets[ctx.p0DataIndex] > 0 ? 'Green' : 'Red')
}};

return (
<Box h="100%" w="100%">
  <Flex m="10px">
    <Button onClick={handleResetZoom}>Reset Zoom</Button>
    <Spacer />
    <Select
      border="1px"
      w={{ base: "50%", md: "25%", lg: "25%" }}
      value={num_days}
      onChange={(e) => setNumDays(Number(e.target.value))}
    >
      <option value={7}>Últimos 7 dias</option>
      <option value={15}>Últimos 15 dias</option>
      <option value={30}>Últimos 30 dias</option>
      <option value={90}>Últimos 90 dias</option>
      <option value={180}>Últimos 180 dias</option>
      <option value={365}>Últimos 365 dias</option>
    </Select>
  </Flex>
  <Box h="100%">
    <Chart ref={chartRef} type="line" options={options} data={data} />
  </Box>
</Box>);
```

cve-dashboard.js

```
 <Card key={l.i}>
      <Button w="5px" h="15px" onClick={() => onPutItem(l)}>
        &times;
      </Button>
      <Componentes data={l.component_name} /> {/* Component being called dynamically */}
 </Card>
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer I found was adding display grid to the box

```
 <Box h="100%" w="100%" display={"grid"}>
```

It works as intended now